# How to install Ubuntu on a m.2 raid (aka. fakeraid) alongside Windows10

Tags: dual-boot, raid

I am not new to Linux, but have had a rather on-off relationship with it. Currently, the computer is running an UEFI m.2 intel RST raid with windows 10.
It should become a dual boot system, however the preferred weapon of choice, the Ubuntu Live USB install is rather ineffective at the moment.

The 1. problem is that Gparted on the Ubuntu LiveUSB does not see the m.2 raid, at all.
The Gparted stand alone usb however, sees it just fine and can partition it too (have shoved space around to make room for Linux that way).

This wiki article seems to be related:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto
but either I don't understand it properly, or it assumes that Ubuntu's system and boot partition are not on the m.2 raid.

So, can someone tell what is missing or misinterpreted?

Comment: Which Ubuntu ISO exists on your Live USB?  Have you verified the download & write to media were flawless, as currently you haven't erased user/operator issues in your question.  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck and software stage age tried cannot be know until we know what you booted/tried; yes the *latest* daily images do self-test to overcome users missing steps but you haven't said what you've tried)

Comment: typos in last comment s/software stage/software stack/; and CD in integrity applies if your ISO is written to CD/DVD/HDD/SSD/thumb-drive or any other media

Comment: Hello, the Ubuntu version on the USB is 19.10-desktop-amd64. The file check returned no error for the files on the drive.